# Registration doesn't create an order given specific registration state

Tags: commerce

I've created a new registration state (Registration in progress) and set it as the default state for new registrations.  Going through the site's course registration process results in a valid registration with this new state, but it will not create a new Commerce order.

A few things to note:

- The registration process works perfectly when registrations have the old default state (Pending payment), i.e. a registration is created and the user is automatically taken to their cart.
- Registrations are done using the [Entity Registration](https://www.drupal.org/project/registration) module.
- Neither of the Commerce Registration nor the Registration Commerce modules are in use on this site.

The basic question is this - what causes a registration to create an order?

I'm guessing I haven't given enough info to get an answer and I apologize for that but I just don't know where to start on this.

Also, I have no idea if this is a Commerce issue or an Entity Registration issue, and I am only posting here because I have had zero luck formulating a question for Google that gets me anything even remotely related to what I am seeing.

Any / all help will be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Dan